# In Chronicle, what happened to Steve?

Tags: chronicle

The last time we see Steve, he was confronting Andrew while flying above some storm clouds.  As Andrew became more and more agitated, we see more and more lightning activity in the storm clouds.

Right when Andrew seems to lose his temper, it appears that lightning strikes, and next thing we know

> we're at Steve's funeral.

Was the lightning coincidental, or did Andrew somehow influence the severity of the storm?

> Did Andrew kill Steve with lightning, or did Steve die because he and Andrew just happened to be in a dangerous spot, and he got unlucky?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a line of dialogue when Matt confronted Andrew after

> the funeral.

Matt says, and I paraphrase because I just saw the movie on Saturday and don't remember it exactly, that

> they found Steve's body in the middle of a field after being struck by lightning. So it seems like he was struck by lightning while talking to Andrew, and then crashed to the ground. Matt notes that there were no reported strikes on the ground, so he assumed that Steve was in the air when it happened, most likely talking to Andrew. So I don't think that Andrew caused the lightning to hit him, but he definitely did let his body fall to the earth (it's not guaranteed that the lightning strike killed him).

I'm not sure if the powers Matt, Steve and Andrew got could influence weather. They really only showed telekinetic and some force field based powers, none of which I think can alter the weather. I feel like if it was intended for weather to be manipulable by their powers, it would have played more of a factor in the climax.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think most people get it wrong. It was Andrew that killed Steve. I think it wasn't coincidental that the lightning struck him. The reason why I don't think it was a coincidence  is because if you listen to Andrew and Matt's confrontation in the cemetery right after Steve's funeral, Matt clearly states that there is no way he could have been struck when there were no lightning strikes recorded in that area, meaning, the lightning literally came out of nowhere. Now I'm not a meteorologist but since Matt said no one else saw the lightning,this probably implies that it was in fact Andrew who was influencing the weather. And it kinda seems that when Andrew got angrier the lightning flared up.

Comment: Matt was referring to where Steve's body was found, not where Steve and Andy had their argument. In fact, throughout their argument, you see lightning striking with increasing frequency, all around them.

Comment: Andrew killed Steve, willfully and with forethought. He understood the Power better than anyone. As his powers, rage and mental instability increased, it became more apparent he would eventually kill the other two because they could potentially challenge him.

Answer (score 3):

How can people here doubt that Andrew killed him when Andrew himself admitted to it? He apologized for it when he visited Steve's grave alone after the funeral. You know -- when he was all "I miss you, I'm sorry, I wish I could take it back" etc.

Comment: "I miss you" means "I miss you".  "I'm sorry" could be "I'm sorry you got accidentally killed" or "I'm sorry I lost my temper and killed you".  I don't remember him saying "I wish I could take it back".  Did he actually say that?  Even if he did, that still doesn't mean it wasn't coincidental lightning (I'm not saying it was a coincidence; merely that Andrew saying those things could mean a number of things, and therefore isn't a convincing argument one way or another).

Answer (score 3):

From the strength of the execution of telekinesis, Andrew simply created a field around the lightning, directing it to Steve. The release of the pent up energy of that lightning is what killed Steve once it connected. The movie follows the definitions and theories of telekinesis.  That doesn't make it flawed; it makes it different.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew researched about the powers they experienced, and throughout the movie he explains that he is an Apex Predator. After killing Steve, I believe Andrew thought he was the most dangerous and strongest living creature on Earth, then taking his anger out on everyone else, anger due to the hard life he suffered with his mother suffering a terrible illness and his Dad abusing him horribly. Believing he had no friends, he kills Steve. Matt then says in the cemetery that there were no lightning strikes.

Andrew killed Steve. When Steve was asking him to calm down and chill, Andrew builds his anger, telling Steve, "Leave me alone!". I believe Andrew then made the lightning strike Steve, leaving Steve lying in the middle of a field.

I don't know what gave them the powers, maybe an alien artifact. Matt says at the end of the movie that he will help people and find out what happened to them. Internet Movie Data Base (IMDB) states that *Chronicle 2* will be coming, but there is no info. Maybe Matt will become a superhero, a superhero named 'Chronicle'?.

Comment: Seems to be a thorough answer, but I would suggest breaking the paragraph up in order to facilitate easier reading.

Answer (score -3):

This is one of the biggest flaws in the movie.

What most people (and the filmmakers included) dont know is that lightning has to make contact with the surface in order to hit. So that there were no reported hits is impossible according to physics. It is also the reason why those big clomps of metal (planes) never get struck by lightning, even when flying thru a storm.

I know they have the other guy say that there were no reported hits at the funeral, just to imply that Andrew did it but that makes the whole thing even more silly.

Also think about this: 
Floating objects can be hit but only when being like 1 centimeter above ground surface or something and the lightning has to be exponentially more powerful to make it happen. And it almost never will for the fact that lightning searches the easiest target As high as possible but still in contact with the surface.

For lightning to hit something floating between the very clouds, would be magic. It would definatly be the work of Andrew and by there making him EXTREMELY powerful. Like waaaaay more powerful than crushing buildings and such.. If he can produce such powerful lightning it would mean he would be able to obliterate the entire world with it.

Comment: Cloud to cloud lightning does occur.  You do not need to be on or near the ground to be struck.  Modern aircraft are struck by lightning on a regular basis, at least once a year, by some estimates.  The last accident attributed to lightning was in 1963.